# Можно ли настроить swiperjs, что бы он слушал изменение, и услышав их менял активный слайд

Tags: reactjs, swiper

Что то такого плана,
что бы при изменении состояния после клика по span
swiper слышал это, и менял активный слайд

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";

const SwaiperBlock = ()=> {


const [indexSlide, setIndexSlide] = useState(1);

return<>

    <span onClick={()=>setIndexSlide(1)} > slide 1 </span>
    <span onClick={()=>setIndexSlide(2)}> slide 2 </span>
    <span onClick={()=>setIndexSlide(3)}> slide 3 </span>

    <Swiper
        initialSlide={indexSlide}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 1
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 2
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 3
        </SwiperSlide>

    </Swiper>
</>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```js
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";

const SwaiperBlock = ()=> {

return<>

    <div className="custom-pagination-div" />

    <Swiper
        initialSlide={indexSlide}
        pagination={{
          el: '.custom-pagination-div',
          clickable: true,
          renderBullet: (index, className) => {
           return '<span style="padding:1rem;" class="' + className + '">' + (index+1) + "</span>";
          },
        }}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 1
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 2
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
            here slide 3
        </SwiperSlide>

    </Swiper>
</>
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваше решение, 
то есть какого то слушателя событий <Swiper> нет,
просто данный вариант не совсем решает мою проблему, но приближает к ее решению